# Pixi.js Axis-aligned Rectangle Masks

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

Pixi.js has a [document](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/wiki/v4-Performance-Tips) that lists a number of performance tips. They are all great bits of advice, but I have trouble understanding and using one of them.

> Axis-aligned Rectangle Masks are the fastest (as they use scissor rect)

I know what "axis-aligned rectangles" are, I just do not understand how to use them in Pixi.js.

I was thinking that I should use a `PIXI.Rectangle`, but a mask of `DisplayObject` is defined to be a `PIXI.Graphics | PIXI.Sprite`.

Is there a hidden trick to this, or is this a regular `PIXI.Graphics` mask with a non-rotated rectangle drawn onto it?

Answer (score 3):

I've received a response from an author of Pixi.js through Gitter.

"Axis-aligned rectangles" are created exactly by calling `drawRect` on `Pixi.Graphics` element.

Comment: An example would be much appreciated